# Some more info about voltage/current electricity safety

Tags: safety

I'm using a 400W PC power supply that is able to deliver at 12V 12 Amperes and 15 Amperes (i' m not sure why there are 2 values). I have connected 3 simple (disk drive) DC motors in parallel and when all of the three run, I get 0.12 Amp on the multimeter. I calculate the watts are 1.44 Watts. When i forcibly stop these with my finger the current jumps to 0.7 Amps (8.4 Watts and more) and growing (the potentiometer i use to control current starts smoking). Now i read that 90mA are able to produce pain, and at 500mA it could be lethal. Can someone advice me by providing some example how i can electrocute myself with such a circuit.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Everything below 48VDC is considered to be safe.

Comment: So the resistance of my body/skin will always protect me with such low voltages?

Comment: I won't say 'always' but the risk is a lot less with voltage below 48VDC.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So it depends on humidity of the skin, cuts and the position electricity is applied? (i.e. across the chest)

Comment: You got it. With 12V there's no way to get hurt unless you lick the wires or plant some electrodes under your skin. We are basically bags of water, but the bag is not a good conductor.

Comment: We are bags of electrolyte solution (aqueous). A very sophisticated control system maintains the electrolyte within tight specifications.

Comment: The smoking potentiometer is more of a hazard.

Comment: @pjc50 Can you please explain, do you mean that the pot actually get's destroyed?

Comment: As a safety issue, the vapors from the smoking pot might be harmful if you breathe them; Also the heat could cause a fire tht could hurt somebody or expensive to clean up after.

Comment: @The Photon I understand. Are the chemical vapors potentially so harmful?

Comment: Yes, it's the carbon track that's actually burning. I very much doubt it's toxic but it is a fire hazard.

Comment: @pjc50 Yes, this morning (due to a short) i watched the plastic of a small cable disappear/burn in front of my eyes in just a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When i forcibly stop these with my finger the current jumps to 0.7 Amps (8.4 Watts and more) and growing (the potentiometer i use to control current starts smoking). Now i read that 90mA are able to produce pain,

When you stop the motor, the current doesn't increase because it is flowing through your body. It increases because the motor's [*stall current*](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/613/what-is-stall-current-and-free-current-of-motors) is higher than its free-running current.

You shouldn't expect to experience electrocution from this, because no current is flowing through your body (or at least, you haven't told us anything that would make us think there is current flowing through your body).

Comment: Hm, I know that by stopping the motor i didn't touch any live connection. I guess by stopping it by physically touching the shaft  the resistance of the motor get's bigger and the power supply provides more amps

Comment: Read the linked Q&A. (Also, if the resistance were to increase, the current draw would decrease, not increase)

Comment: Ok, i will read the articles